# webpack optimize minimize returns boolean, not factory

Tags: javascript, webpack

simple script I'm trying to minify

**script.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log('webpack script');
};
```

**cl args**

```
$ webpack script.js script.min.js --optimize-minimize
$ webpack script.js script.bundled.js
```

**script.min.js**

when executed in the browser, it returns `false`

```
var script = !function(o){function r(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var n=t[e]={exports:{},id:e,loaded:!1};return o[e].call(n.exports,n,n.exports,r),n.loaded=!0,n.exports}var t={};return r.m=o,r.c=t,r.p="",r(0)}([function(o,r){o.exports=function(){console.log("webpack script")}}]);
script; // => false
```

**script.bundled.js**

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = function() {
      console.log('webpack script');
    }

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Now I can do this in a browser

```
var script = /* non-minified bundle */
typeof script; // => function
```

works fine. Not sure why `--optimize-minimize` isn't working.

Comment: Why are you to get the value of `script`? Webpack doesn't return a factory, it returns an IIFE (using a shorthand notation with a `!` instead of braces). The code is executed automatically.

Comment: @nils it doesn't return an iife, it clearly returns `__webpack_require__(0)`

Comment: My bad for misusing the word *returns*. What I meant is: Webpack *generates* an IIFE, meaning it is self executing (and you shouldn't care about the return value). So you don't need to run it. On the other hand, since `script.js` is your entry point, it shouldn't contain a `module.exports` statement, it should just execute the code that you want to have executed (i.e. `console.log('webpack script');`). Unless of course you are going for an unconventional way of using webpack, in which case you wont be able to use the minified version as it uses the `!` IIFE (which always returns a boolean).

Comment: ah right, overlooked actually exporting something that doesn't need to be exported. I'll mark that as the answer if you submit it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack generates an IIFE, meaning it is self executing and the return-value doesn't matter in this case. So you don't need to run it.

On the other hand, since **script.js** is your entry point, it shouldn't contain a `module.exports` statement, it should just execute the code that you want to have executed, in this example:

```
console.log('webpack script');
```